# Two group by two columns and count on each

Tags: t-sql, count, group-by, ssrs-2008

```
Name  | Fruit  |  Red  
John  | Apple  |  Yes  
John  | Apple  |  No  
John  | Pear   |  Yes  
Mike  | Mango  |  No
```

How can I get a result that looks like:

```
Name | Fruits total | Red fruits total  
John | 3            | 2
```

How can I use a value from first column in two count operations for another columns? Is it possible?
I need this query for a ssrs report if that could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, if you are filtering by the name then you can use `count(*)` and then use an aggregate function with a `CASE` to determine the total number of fruit that is red:

```
select name,
  count(*) TotalFruit,
  sum(case when red='Yes' then 1 else 0 end) TotalRed
from yourtable
where name = 'John'
group by name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34868/1)

Result:

```
| NAME | TOTALFRUIT | TOTALRED |
--------------------------------
| John |          3 |        2 |
```